# Structure padding

Tags: c, structure

I was trying to understand why structure padding is the reason structures cannot be compared by memcmp. 
One small thing i dont understand about structure padding is this...
why should "`a short be 2 byte aligned"`or`"a long be 4 byte aligned"`. I understand it is with their sizes but why can they not appear at any byte boundary?

Or in other words `"why is 0x10004566  not a valid location for a long variable but 0x10004568 is?"`

Comment: If you go all the way down towards zero, starting with 0x10004566, the first place you can put 4 bytes is at 0x00000002, thereby "wasting" 2 bytes of memory (bytes 0x00000000 and 0x00000001).

Comment: Makes sense. But isnt 2 bytes of space small enough when compared to appending padding (which occurs a lot of times).

Comment: Imagine you want to buy batteries. They come in packs of 8, but you only want 7 ... so you open the packet and remove 1. Next time you want another 7 ... so you take the 1 remaining from before, open another pack and remove 2. and so on ... Now imagine you get 8 and throw 1 away. next time you get another 8 and throw another away, ... --- bytes are cheaper than batteries :)

Comment: So you mean the overhead involved in calculating the exact location for such a read(if it doesnt involve padding) would be cumbersome and takes many cycles. Instead you can just prefer to use padding(as bytes are cheaper :) )... Just making sure i got it right.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Reading in aligned blocks of 4 (or 8, or 16, ... 1024 ...) bytes is more natural to the hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory alignment is a very important issue when optimizing a program for speed. C, being a language that - generally - puts strong emphasis on speed, likes to enforce some rules which may make the program faster.

The limitation of aligned and unaligned memory accesses comes directly from the hardware used for fetching the data from the memory, which usually fetches it in chunks which are equal to the machine word in size. Say you want to access a doubleword (4 bytes) stored at location 101. This means that the memory controller would firstly have to (probably) issue a read of a doubleword at location 100, then another read of a doubleword at location 104, and then splice the individual bytes from locations 101, 102, 103, and 104 together. The whole operation takes (hypothetically) two clock cycles.

If you want to access a doubleword at location 100, there's no such issue, which should be illustrated clearly enough by the example I provided.

In fact, misaligned data access is such a big issue that SSE instructions (the "aligned" versions, there are also "misaligned" versions which don't do that) will cause a general protection fault if you try to access misaligned data with those.

As a rule of thumb, it never hurts to align 4-byte data on a 4-byte boundary, 8-byte data on a 8-byte boundary, and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

Because some platforms (i.e. CPUs) physically don't support "mis-aligned" memory accesses.  Other platforms support them, but in a much slower fashion.

The padding you get in a struct is dependent on the choices your compiler makes, but it will be making those choices in order to satisfy the specific requirements of the CPU the code is targeted at.

Answer (score 1):

The only additional example I can think of with respect to alignment is transfer of data, transfers of data (depending on the architecture) goes in blocks of say 32 bytes for example, if your data crosses a boundary it could require 2 transfers to receive the data, rather then 1.